# Show comment pop up links as text only

Tags: comments

I'm trying to show `comments_popup_links()` function as a text only,not as a link. Is it possible to prevent it from being a link.

Below snippet creates links to the comment, but I don't want it to be links.

```
<?php
  comments_popup_link( 'No comments', '1 comment', '% comments');
?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For that matter, don't use comments_popup_link(). Use [comments_number()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/comments_number) instead. This has the same function but not linked.

```
<?php comments_number( 'no responses', 'one response', '% responses' ); ?>
```